# What's the usecase of volatile operations on std::atomic<T>?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, volatile

There has been a lot of debate going on concerning the usefulness of `volatile` in multi-threaded code. Most people agree, that the principal usecases of `volatile` are mostly for bare metal applications such as device drivers and interrupt handlers, but not to make a variable of built-in type thread-safe. In fact, volatile has lead to much confusion because of this.

However, it has been added to function overloads of `std::atomic<T>` types, which suggests that there be a usecase for this. What are usecases of these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general usefulness to `volatile` in the sense that compiler MUST not optimise away accesses to that variable. However, in this case, I think it's mainly because the input MAY be `volatile` - just like in case of `const`, you can "add" but not "remove" `volatile` attribute to a passed in paramater.

Thus:

```
int foo(volatile int *a)
{
    ... 
}
```

will accept:

```
int x;
volatile int y;

foo(&x);
foo(&y);
```

where if you didn't write `volatile`, the compiler should not accept the `foo(&y);` variant.